# Circular dependency of template class and non-template class

Tags: c++, templates

File ex1.hpp (definition of template class):

```
#ifndef EX1_HPP
#define EX1_HPP

#include "ex2.hpp"

template <class T>
class Ex1{
public:
    void Ex1method(){
        Ex2 a; // using nontemplate class object
        a.Ex2method();
    }
};

#endif
```

File ex2.hpp (definition of nontemplate class):

```
#ifndef EX2_HPP
#define EX2_HPP

#include "ex1.hpp"

class Ex2{
public:
    void Ex2method();
};

#endif
```

File ex2.cpp (definition of nontemplate class method):

```
#include "ex2.hpp"

void Ex2::Ex2method()
{
    Ex1<int> e; // using template class object
    e.Ex1method();
}
```

Compilation error:

```
ex1.hpp:10:9: error: ‘Ex2’ was not declared in this scope
ex1.hpp:10:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘a’
ex1.hpp:11:9: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
```

How can be such circular dependency between nontemplate class and template class resolved? I cannot be definition of nontemplate class methods to implementation file, because it will cause linker error. If I place forward declaration of Ex2 class in file ex1.hpp, then error is:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Ex2’
error: forward declaration of ‘struct Ex2’
```

Comment: Ex2.hpp does not appear to need Ex1.hpp; why does it include it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't include `ex1.hpp` in `ex2.hpp`, it is not necessary there. You don't have a circular dependency with your headers.

Include both headers (or just `ex1.hpp`) in your `.cpp` file and all should be good.

Answer (score 1):

From ex2.h, move the

```
#include "ex1.hpp"
```

to the ex2.cpp

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to include `ex1.hpp` from `ex2.hpp` at all. Include it from `ex2.cpp` instead, and the circular dependency will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Should you really need `Ext1` in `Ext2`, for example when you have an `Ext1` member in `Ext2`, you can still make the use of `Ext2` depend on `T`. Then you only need the full definition of `Ext2` when the member function of the template is actually called.

```
class Ext2;

template <class T, class>
class Identity {
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
class Ex1{
public:
    void Ex1method(){
        typename Identity<Ex2, T>::type a;
        a.Ex2method();
    }
};
```

Now the user of `Ext1method` can include the header of `Ext2` if he wishes to call that member function. No need to include `Ext2.hpp` within `Ext1.hpp` now anymore. But this complication is only needed or useful if

- You cannot omit including `Ext1.hpp` within `Ext2.pph`, or
- You don't want users that don't call `Ext1method` to have `Ext2.h` included automatically ("name pollution").